# Windows magically adds languages to my keyboard layout list

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

Two new keyboards have somehow appeared in my keyboard layout list: [image] [image]

The bottom two (German, and English - United Kingdom) are emphatically *not* in my system language list, so I cannot remove them!

I was browsing the Internet for the past few hours, so could it be caused by Chrome? (E.g. when typing text in a textbox with `lang=de`, it could have somehow added a German keyboard for me). If so, how can I disable this, and prevent other programs from doing the same in the future?

Also, how do I remove those layouts now? The problem might go away if I log off and on again, but I'd prefer not to have to do it every time.

Comment: Have you added those keyboards on other machines where you sign in with the same Microsoft account?

Comment: In the past, perhaps, but right now I only have one computer.

Answer (score 0):

You got at the advanced settings the possibility to turn this off. I guess that's one solution you could try and would help (it's maybe for you a little bit too late but for the next one not).

Under `Control Panel -> Clock, Language and Region -> Language -> Advanced Settings` you got a header with **"Switching input methods"** and a checkbox with **"Let me set a different input method for each app window"**. Unchecking this box may solve the problem.